# Processing in Android mode: where is my log file?

Tags: android, processing

I'm testing a Processing sketch in Android mode, code taken from
a generic tutorial. I know (I guess?), that the sketch saves a log file:

```
import android.util.Log;
```

being line at the beginning of the sketch, and then 
some call in the middle of code like this:

```
Log.e("Aldrin", "Armostrong");
```

Do you know where the file is saved? I looked inside
the sketch folder but nothing. Obviously I'm a very newby
in Android.
Thanks

PS: working on a Linux system (Debian 7)

Comment: Please read https://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Answer (score 2):

In order to see the log file:

1:  localise the folder "platform-tools"
    inside the Android sdk folder, in my case:

```
android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

2: inside there is a script called "adb". 
   Open a shell and launch it with the argument "logcat"

```
./adb logcat
```

3: As soon as your sketch runs, the messages defined in
   the Log.e("Aldrin", "Armostrong");
   are streamed in the shell!